# Where is the RestRequest class?

Tags: c#, .net, mailgun

In the C# tab of [the getting started of maingun API](http://documentation.mailgun.net/quickstart.html#sending-messages), I find the following code.

```
public static RestResponse SendSimpleMessage() {
       RestClient client = new RestClient();
       client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2";
       client.Authenticator =
               new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                          "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0");
       RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
       request.AddParameter("domain",
                            "samples.mailgun.org", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
       request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
       request.AddParameter("from", "Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>");
       request.AddParameter("to", "sergeyo@profista.com");
       request.AddParameter("to", "serobnic@mail.ru");
       request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
       request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
       request.Method = Method.POST;
       return client.Execute(request);
}
```

When I google the name of the class, I find several reference to this class in different contexts. However, I can't seem to find the fully qualified name of the RestRequest  class anywhere on the mailgun website, google or MSDN to find it's documentation.

**Anybody can point out where is this class defined ?**

Comment: you need this library: http://restsharp.org/

Comment: No idea why Mailgun doesn't add this to their own documentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code looks like it uses [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Comment: Even if the original code doesn't use RestSharp, I suggest converting the code to use it anyway. RestSharp is **by far the best** rest client library available!

Answer (score 2):

RestSharp is available from NuGet.  Install it from there.

Answer (score -1):

I run in the same issue. But I found out that if you are using JAVA 8 you don't needs any external librairy but just what java provide already here is my code example.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class EmailDAO {

public static Response sendNewPasswordMessage() {
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new BasicAuthenticator("api","yourkey"));

WebTarget target = client.target("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/your-domain/messages");

MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedHashMap();
formData.add("from", "Test <postmaster@test.net>");
formData.add("to", "anyone@test.net");
formData.add("subject", "Hello world");
formData.add("html", "Hello world <br /> <br /> ");

Invocation invocation = target.request().buildPost(Entity.form(formData));
return invocation.invoke();
}

}
```

Hopes it helps.

Comment: This is a `C#`-related question, not `Java`.